# How to break up one print command in two lines of code in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I want to print one continuous message with two lines of code using print, how can I do this?

```
print('Hello how are you')
print('today?')
```

But this gives me

```
Hello how are you
today?
```

While I want

```
Hello how are you today?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `end=' '` to replace the newline with a space:

```
print('Hello how are you', end=' ')
print('today?')
```

Answer (score 4):

@Martijn's answer is complete, but My Mileage Varies.

As a general rule, I think multiple calls to `print` is ugly. I prefer to see the string built on multiple lines then printed in the same line. For instance:

```
first_part = "Hello how are you"
second_part = "today?"

thing_to_print = ' '.join([first_part,second_part])
print(thing_to_print)
```

the `end` parameter on `print` is useful, but (to me) it feels more hack than help.

Comment: You've replaced one call to `print` with a list construction, a method lookup, and a function invocation that allocates a new string object. This might be overkill without knowing more about where the two strings come from, let alone if they really are string literals.

Comment: @chepner It's certainly not compact code. *In real life* I would use `print("{} {}".format("Hello how are you","today?"))` but since the OP is using obviously-throwaway code, it seems silly to assume that their strings will be so simple.

Answer (score 4):

An elegant solution would be to use two lines of code (as you are asking) but only use the print() function once. Look closely at the parenthes:

```
print('Hello how are you',
      'today?')
```

It will print:

```
Hello how are you today?
```

You can just leave the print-parenthesis open and indent nicely. This answer is "using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and braces" as learnt from:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation
(PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code)

print() is also automatically providing one space respectively between the elements - in case you are wondering where the space between "you" and "today" came from.

note: In your question you are not explaining why you need "to print one continuous message with two lines of code using print". So maybe you have code where your two calls of the print statement are not in two lines following each other. In such a case my answer would of course not work. But your example has got both print() functions in successive lines, so I am giving an "obvious" answer.

Comment: This should be the correct solution. It is Pythonic and very useful for large print statements. I use this all the time. Just don't forget that it doesn't add an extra space for you on each new line!

Comment: @Engineer_Chris thanks, and could you please elaborate on your warning about no extra spaces? My answer was written long ago and I believe I did check it first. I found that spaces are provided between all the elements. You mention "new line" while the print-out here is in only one line. Are you giving info for the special case if the print-out will ever over-run the space available in one line? Maybe give an example?

Comment: Your answer is still valid, but there is an alternate that is similar and even simpler: `print('Hello, how are you '<br>'today?')` which does not insert an extra space between the strings (it is easy to confuse it between a multi-line string using triple quotes). A comma between the strings is not necessary. I added an example in my answer below, to add extra clarity.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Martin's excellent example, here is the same print statement without needing commas (just a continuation of the same string):

```
print('Hello, how are you '
      'today?')
# Output: Hello, how are you today?
```

Strings enclosed within parenthesis can use a similar style:

```
string = ('Hello, how are you '
          'today?')
print(string)
# Output: Hello, how are you today?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a new variable with *f-string* to concatenate both strings, so any time you call that variable it brings to you both strings concatenated.

e.g;

## Any time you call greetings variable below this code it brings to you h and g.

```
h = ("Hello, how are you")
g = ("today?")

greetings = f"{h} {g}"
print(greetings)
```

##### Output

```
Hello, how are you today?
```